# Spring Boot Html to Image (Html Rendering)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, html-rendering

I am using spring boot and want to create Image from Html

I am using `SpringTemplateEngine` and `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver` to get rendered html But when I am creating the image, the css is not Applied on it.

I also have to replace images in html, so it's necessary to render html.

Below is my code, any help will be highly appreciated

```java
SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");

templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

Context ctx = new Context();

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

ctx.setVariable("todayDate", dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
ctx.setVariable("name", "Manoj");
final String result = templateEngine.process("index", ctx);
System.out.println("result:" + result);

// Change the image type to demonstrate that GIF and PNG still work properly
String fileType = "png";

HtmlImageGenerator originalGenerator = new HtmlImageGenerator();
originalGenerator.loadHtml(result);
originalGenerator.saveAsImage("cards/original" + "_" + fileType + "." + fileType);
```

Comment: Hello is the CSS, inside the HTML page ? or in another external file?

Comment: CSS is inside html page. All CSS applied except fonts

Comment: @EFOE Below is my HTML
`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Title</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lacquer&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
  .aa{
   background: #000000;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-family: 'Lacquer';
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <p class="aa">This is Main Page</p>
</body>
</html>
`

Comment: Were you able to do it? If yes then please share any reference link